# Embedded Windows Media Player not obeying 'transparentatstart' in IE9/10

Tags: html, windows, media-player

I have this html...

```
<div class="video2" style="display: none; width: 470px; height: 310px; background-image: url(http://www.jameshay.co.uk/images/Competitions/SipplicityPreview.jpg); background-position: top left; background-repeat: no-repeat;">
    <object id="mediaplayer" classid="clsid:22D6F312-B0F6-11D0-94AB-0080C74C7E95" codebase="http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/mplayer/en/nsmp2inf.cab#version=5,1,52,701"
        standby="loading microsoft windows media player components..." type="application/x-oleobject"
        width="470" height="310">
        <param name="transparentatstart" value="true" />
        <param name="animationatstart" value="false" />
        <param name="autostart" value="false" />
        <param name="filename" value="http://www.jameshay.co.uk/videos/MiSIPP_Overview.wmv" />
    </object>
</div>
```

... but the background image isn't showing, I'm just getting a black screen (possibly the first frame of the video, though I did ask the agency to make that frame a preview image).  Now annoyingly it sometimes shows, and sometimes doesn't.  If I press the Stop button when the page first loads, the image appears.  F5'ing may still show the image a few times before it goes back to black.

Has anyone got any hints on how I can fix this?  It's looks so much nicer with a preview showing properly, rather than a large black square.